# Pulling up to 12 RTMP streams

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am VERY new to this site! I have been reading the codes for the past few nights! From Publishing a flash project with network access so it can contact the internet to RTMP applications and streaming. But I have hit a wall and I do not want to go off the wrong path as most of my work is bits and pieces of helpful information on this site. And please appologize I'm not the boss of a company, so I do not do much of the coding any more and i have surely forgotten most of my PHP coding background, Please do not smite me for dumb or"noob". But since I have made it this far with the flash and actionscripts3 programming I thought it would not hurt if I asked a few questions from much smarter people!

Currently I am working on a single windowed flash project that will allow me to pull up to 12 live RTMP streams. Currently with everything i have been able to do, I have a working code so far to JUST pull a single RTMP string. Took me 3 days of code that was pulled off the internet, to get it to work. i have been successful in getting one stream with action script

```
package com.endseven {

    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;

    import com.endseven.RTMPStream;

    public class Downstream extends RTMPStream {

        /* the constructor. */
        public function Downstream():void {

            trace("Downstream object has been created."); // debug trace..

            this.oVideo = new Video(640, 480);

            this.oConnection = new NetConnection();
            this.oConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, eNetStatus, false, 0, true);
            this.oConnection.connect(this.sMediaServerURL);

        }

        /* triggered when a net status event is received. */
        private function eNetStatus(oEvent1:NetStatusEvent) {

            trace("NetStatusEvent: " + oEvent1.info.code); // debug trace..

            switch (oEvent1.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":

                // create a stream for the connection..
                this.oNetStream = new NetStream(oConnection);
                this.oNetStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, eNetStatus, false, 0, true);
                this.oNetStream.bufferTime = 5; // set this to whatever is comfortable..

                // listen for meta data..
                this.oMetaData.onMetaData = eMetaDataReceived;
                this.oNetStream.client = this.oMetaData;

                // attach the stream to the stage..
                this.oVideo.attachNetStream(oNetStream);
                this.oNetStream.play(sStreamName);
                this.addChildAt(this.oVideo, 0);

                trace("Connected to the RTMP server."); // debug trace..
                break;

            case "NetConnection.Connect.Closed":

                trace("Disconnected from the RTMP server."); // debug trace..
                break;

            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":

                trace("This stream is currently unavailable."); // debug trace..
                break;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is the actionscript3 code that is the only code i have gotten to work. But this only pulls in a single stream on a single display. I mean I could work with this and just have twelve of them. But that seems to be a waste. What is the best method to get this to work. I am very new so this next question seems even dumb to me! But cant i just create 12 flash files and import them and arrange them in a single project?

Comment: You could actually create a SWF (flash file output) and load it in as a module 12 times, but creating a module based architecture isn't worth it unless you plan to change which modules are loaded (it makes communicating between the modules difficult).  You're best off just creating 12 instances of this class and doing the addChildAt() part from "outside" this class wherever they're created so you can manage their positions there (ie myStreams[i].x=100*i; addChild(myStreams[i]));

Comment: Well with the code above, how would i make it so that when someone clicks it, that it maximizes. I have been trying to figure it out. but all the coding i use is not working AT ALL! The simplest thing. I need the video to be 175x17 and when someone clicks it, it goes to the original screen resolution of the video

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with the inner workings of NetStream but in general you should be able to just update the size of the Video display object being used to show the stream.

Comment: Now that you have a class that can stream one video, try to make another class that can instantiate multiple instances of your "streaming" class and tell them to play. Add functions to your "streaming" class that allow the "master" class to control all of the "streaming" classes. For example: when/where they should connect, when to play/pause/stop the video, when to maximize/minimize the size of the video.

Comment: To elaborate on how to start: your first task should be how to divide up the available screen space for 12 (or however many) videos. Once you get the layout down, then try to make all 12 start playing. Then modify the master/streamer classes so you can tell each one which stream to play. And so on...